# Change background color in Image Editor for transparent image

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

I'm rendering an image with a transparent background, which will eventually be included in a figure with a white background. In the Image Editor, blender displays the transparent regions as a grey/black checkerboard pattern. This is helpful, but I would like to get an idea how my image looks on a white background whenever I re-render.
Is there anyway to temporarily set the background color of the Image Editor?

Here's what it looks like, and as you can see, it's a little hard to tell if the render would look pretty on a white background:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the *Compositor*, with this node setup:

[image]

It just takes the areas with an Alpha value, and replaces them with the color specified in the Alpha Over node.

Comment: @DanHickstein If this answer has satisfactorily answered your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it :)

Comment: Oh yes, the most important part! :)